# Google map marker place is not set as center of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have integrate google map in my admin panel, in which I provide 
Fields : city name, address, latitude, longitude,
Button near to address:  view map

In which I allowed to user that manually choose their coordinates points using draggable marker.

- At first time when address is enter, it works fine and marker place is set as screen,
- But when user is set manually position of address using draggable marker at that time, I update my coordinates.
- Now next time user can and show same records and view google map at that time marker place is not set as centre but set as left top corner.

I used symfony2.3 & twig template

Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key={{ google_api_key }}&libraries=places">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function callGmap(latitude, longitude, coordinatescall) {
    var zoomlevel = 8;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mapOptions = {
        zoom: zoomlevel,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLatlng.lat(), myLatlng.lng()),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
    });
    marker.setMap(gmap);
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmap, 'resize');
    gmap.setZoom(zoomlevel);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (marker) {
        var latLng = marker.latLng;
        $("#collegelife_commonbundle_university_latitude").val(latLng.lat());
        $("#collegelife_commonbundle_university_longitude").val(latLng.lng());
    });
}
function initialize() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({address: "{{ address }}"}, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude, longitude;
            latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            callGmap(latitude, longitude, false);
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
$(function () {
    $("#fModal").on("show", function () {
        var addresscall = "";
        var coordinatescall = false;
        alert("resetmarker");
        var cityname = $("#collegelife_commonbundle_university_cityid option:selected").text();
        var address = $("#collegelife_commonbundle_university_address").val();
        var latitude = $("#collegelife_commonbundle_university_latitude").val();
        var longitude = $("#collegelife_commonbundle_university_longitude").val();
        if (null !== latitude && null !== longitude && latitude !== "" && longitude !== "") {
            coordinatescall = true;
        } else if (null !== address && address !== "") {
            addresscall = address;
        } else if (null !== cityname && cityname !== "") {
            addresscall = cityname;
        } else {
            addresscall = {{ google_default_pin_location }};
        }

        if (coordinatescall === true) {
            alert('coordinates call');
            callGmap(latitude, longitude, true);
        } else if (addresscall != "") {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({address: addresscall}, function (results, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude, longitude;
                    latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    callGmap(latitude, longitude, false);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you give me a example into http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Create example. with code you tried to jsfiddle.net